# Looping through columns and dataframes to aggregate data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, aggregate

I'm trying to sum the values in several columns, and repeat this process in multiple dataframes. I have run the aggregate function outside of a for loop, and it has produced the desired results.

However, inside a for loop, I get the error "object not found" when trying to loop through dataframes, and the error "variable lengths differ" when trying to loop through column names. Any advice on how to resolve one or both of these errors? Is there a better way to do this altogether? I've looked through the forum extensively and none of the previous suggestions have resolved the issue. Thanks for reading!

```
for (i in colnames(m)){
n <- paste("m", i, sep = "")
n <- aggregate(
i~key + plot + blk + trt + field + timepoint + time_code, 
data=m, FUN = sum)
}

ilist <- list(m, d, ss, seg)
for (i in 1:length(ilist)){
n <- paste(i, sep = "")
n <- aggregate(
stems~key + plot + blk + trt + field + timepoint + time_code, 
data=i, FUN = sum)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
stems~key + plot + blk + trt + field + timepoint + time_code, data=i, FUN = sum)
```

You are setting the data to the index of the loop. You need to do:

```
stems~key + plot + blk + trt + field + timepoint + time_code, data=ilist[i], FUN = sum)
```

I'm not sure whether this will solve all your issues with this. As to your other question about whether there is a better way - perhaps have a look at `lapply`?

Comment: Thanks! I am still getting the "object not found error," so there must be an issue somewhere else. The code does work outside the loop still. I will look into lapply as well.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the rules from other languages' `for` loops, instead of R's specific rules.

I would re-write your code thus (although, remember, I haven't seen your data):

```
nameList <- colnames(m)    
for (i in length(nameList)){
  n <- paste(nameList[m], i, sep = "")
  n <- aggregate(
    i~key + plot + blk + trt + field + timepoint + time_code, 
    data=nameList[m], FUN = sum)
}

ilist <- list(m, d, ss, seg)
for (i in 1:length(ilist)){
  n <- paste(ilist[i], sep = "")
  n <- aggregate(
    stems~key + plot + blk + trt + field + timepoint + time_code, 
    data=ilist[i], FUN = sum)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am new to for loops in R, so I appreciate the syntax clarification. Using your code still returns "object not found," so there must be an issue somewhere else. The code does work outside the loop, so I'm perplexed.

Comment: You probably have to change `data=nameList[m]` into something different. But, not being familiar with your data, I have no idea what you need to change it to.